# run a batch file from ftp

Tags: ftp, batch-file

The title basically says it all. I have done endless hours of research trying to find out how to run a bat file from an FTP.

Long story short I have a Bat to shut down a server and I need to be able to execute said bat from an FTP. Only problem is (obviously) I can not double click and run that bat because the FTP wants to download that file. Is there any way to get that file to run from an FTP?

Comment: Why do you 'need' to execute the .bat file from an FTP server?

Comment: the computer that is running the ftp server would have to be running some other server that lets you do that.. either that, or if you were  a hacker then possibly you could abuse the ftp server and run anything, though I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 5):

It is not fully clear what you are trying to achieve, but

- If you are trying to run the batch file on the FTP server itself: this is not possible using FTP.
- If you want to run the batch file locally then you must copy it from the FTP server to the local system (i.e. download it) and run it there.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a .bat to shut down a server and I need to be able to execute said bat

Easily done...

> from an FTP.

But not from FTP. FTP is a **file transfer** protocol.  It is designed to transfer files. It is not intended (or equipped) to execute commands on a server.

> Is there any way to get that file to run from an FTP?

No. Best (or worst since it is an ugly hack) you can do is to set up a job on the server which checks for the presence of a file in one of the FTP folders and then acts on it.  E.g. every 1 minutes check if 'reboot_please.txt' is present and if it is then remove the file and reboot the game server.

(You can skip removing the file tand leave that over to the user, at the risk of wondering why a game server keeps restarting every minute).

Note that you would initiate this from the server. Not from an FTP client.

A better way would be to give the users actual access to the server. How you do that depends on your current setup. Using a batch file indicates some kind of windows, but for more detailed answers we really need more information.